# How to create an optimized model, tables and the relationship between them?

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, eloquent, relationship

I have development custom project where have database tables:

- users
- candidates
- companies
- scopes
- skills

**Users table:**

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('nickname')->unique();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->boolean('type')->default(0); // 0 = candidate and 1 = company
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Candidates table:**

```php
Schema::create('candidates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('lastname')->nullable();
    $table->string('surname')->nullable();
    $table->text('about')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Companies table:**

```php
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedInteger('logo');
    $table->foreign('logo')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('images')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->text('about')->nullable();
    $table->string('website')->nullable();
    $table->integer('employees')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Scopes table:**

```php
Schema::create('scopes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Skills table:**

```php
Schema::create('skills', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Here any users type have scopes and skills. I can solve this solution with creating one table:

**Attributes table:**

```php
Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->morphs('model');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Example data inside **attributes** table:

```php
----------------------------------------
| id | user_id | model_id | model_type |
----------------------------------------
| 15 |   176   |  34458   | App\Scope  |
----------------------------------------
| 29 |   245   |  17654   | App\Skill  |
----------------------------------------
```

But in this solution there is one bad side for me, this is the repetition of the string name of the model on each line of the record in the table. For example:

**Models table:**

```php
Schema::create('models', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Note:** It may be impossible to create a module with the name of the **Model**, so you may need to create it with a different name, for example: **Reference**

Example data inside **models** table:

```php
-------------------
| id |    name    |
-------------------
| 10 | App\Scope  |
-------------------
| 11 | App\Skill  |
-------------------
```

After creating the **models** table, the structure of the **attribute** table changes to:

**Attributes table:**

```php
Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('model_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('models')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedInteger('content_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now how can I create the right relationship inside models to get candidates or company user types skills or scopes?

I have custom relationships inside Users model:

```php
public function candidate()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Candidate::class);
}

public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
}
```

Now, I need inside **Candidate** and **Company** model like this relationships:

```php
public function skills()
{
    // Some code here
}

public function scopes()
{
    // Some code here
}
```

In general get users skills or scopes like this:

```php
$user->candidate->scopes
$user->company->skills
```

If you have another suggestion for solving my problem, please offer your suggestion. If I made a mistake somewhere, correct me if it is possible.

Comment: have you tried creating 1 to many relationship between candidate and scopes and company to skills? candidate->hasMany(scope::class, 'foreign key' ,'primarykey'); similarly company and skills?

Answer (score 0):

Methink your primary ORM construction error is in this line:

```
$table->boolean('type')->default(0); // 0 = candidate and 1 = company
```

This is not solvable with the use of Laravel's ORM. You will have to replace this line with

```
$table->unsignedInteger('candidate_id')->nullable()->index();
$table->unsignedInteger('company_id')->nullable()->index();
```

and start from there. As it can either be a candidate or a company, one of the values will be empty. Easy to check. As there are only 2 possible options, a polymorphic relationship is not really needed. Once you get over that check, your ORM hierarchy will outline itself.

You only have to take care that **if** a candidate becomes a company or visa versa, you make sure the other value gets nullified. This can all be done in Model's mutators or a personalized public function so you don't have to worry about it in the Controllers/Views.

For example `$user->choice->scopes;` where you add a User Model function `getChoiceAttribute()`

```
public function getChoiceAttribute() {
  if ($this->candidate) {
    return $this->candidate;
  }
  if ($this->company) {
    return $this->company;
  }
  return null;
}
```

The same applies to a setter function `setChoiceAttribute()` in case a candidate becomes a company. This only applies if you save or update a record.

To know in the view if you are working with candidates or companies, just check on `$user->choice->getTable();`.